# neo4j Execution engine NoClassDefFoundError CypherOptionParser

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to execute a cypher query using an embedded neo4j 2.2.1 database and get an class not found exception:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypher/internal/CypherOptionParser
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.createCompiler(ExecutionEngine.scala:212)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.<init>(ExecutionEngine.scala:52)
```

At the following line of code

```
    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb, StringLogger.DEV_NULL );
```

The jar files neo4j-cypher-2.2.1.jar and neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2-2.2.1.jar are in my build path. What is causing this exception?

Comment: How are you running this?  (I assume inside of eclipse because you're mentioning build path) What is your complete build path?

Answer (score 1):

There are two `ExecutionEngine` classes, one in package `org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat` and one in `org.neo4j.cypher`. Typically you should use the first one in Neo4j <= 2.1.x.

In Neo4j 2.2 `ExecutionEngine` is deprecated. Instead use the two `execute` methods in [`GraphDatabaseService`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html).